# Computer restarts after selecting ''try ubuntu'' or ''install ubuntu''

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bios

I have my bios set like this:

[image: Screenshot]

But no matter what I do the computer just keeps restarting when I select to try ubuntu or install it.

Comment: Where are you trying to Boot or install from?

Comment: From USB bootable created with UNetbootin

Comment: If you're using UEFI, do not currently use Unetbootin with Debian iso files due to a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I have only the option to install UEFI or LEGACY+UEFI.
I tried UNetbootin and Rufus with the same result.

Comment: I would just burn the .iso to a DVD.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have DVDs available with more than 700MB.

I can use the ''try ubuntu gnome'' button but not the ''install ubuntu gnome'', that only reboots my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57074/discussion-between-j-doe-and-eodcraft-staff).

Answer (score 0):

I have a motherboard that may be related to yours -- an [MSI A88X-G43](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/A88X-G43.html#hero-overview) -- and it's been troublesome at boot time. About half the time, it reboots, much as you describe, at some point soon after it begins executing initial RAM disk (initrd) code. I have yet to fully diagnose the problem, though; it's usually been easier to just try rebooting multiple times until I get a solid boot. After that, the machine is stable. (It's a [MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/) backend and frontend, so it stays up for days, and often months, at a time.)

When I first got this system, it did reliably boot Fedora; but I was replacing an older motherboard and already had a Mythbuntu installation on my disks and so I did not want to completely re-install a new distribution. I discovered that it was reliable booting a 3.12-series kernel that I compiled myself (the Ubuntu 14.04 I was running used a 3.13-series kernel), so I used my locally-compiled kernel for a while and hoped that the problem would eventually be fixed. (I filed a [bug report,](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80141) but it wasn't taken seriously.) The problem has varied in severity -- or maybe it's just randomness at work.

If you're running into a similar issue, you could try another distribution, or try rebooting multiple times in the hopes of getting a clean boot. If your intended use scenario involves frequent reboots, then the latter is obviously not a good solution.

It's conceivable that there's a boot-time kernel option you could pass via GRUB (or whatever boot loader you use) that would help; however, I don't have any suggestions for things to try. My suspicion is that the problem is caused, or at least triggered, by something in the initrd file, not in the kernel itself.

If the motherboard is new, it might be worth considering returning it for another one of another brand. (FWIW, I've got an ASRock motherboard with the same AMD A10-6700 CPU model that's in my MSI board, and the ASRock has never exhibited boot problems.)

Sorry for not having anything more definitive. I can't even be sure that your problem is the same as mine, but I thought my experience might be helpful.