# UbuntuGNOME fresh install stuck on boot (dualboot with WIN10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nomodeset

Today I installed Ubuntu Gnome from a bootable USB alongside Windows 10 in my computer.

Previously, as seen on this question, [Computer restarts after selecting ''try ubuntu'' or ''install ubuntu''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904263/computer-restarts-after-selecting-try-ubuntu-or-install-ubuntu) , I had some problems. I used a different usb bootable software and then, selected the option ''try ubuntu GNOME''.

It booted without a problem and then I selected ''install ubuntu GNOME''. No problem.
Right now when I turn on my computer I can select if I want to boot Ubuntu GNOME or windows.

Windows10 boots nicely (i'm currently on it). 
BUT, Ubuntu GNOME just gets stuck when I select it (or if I wait 10 seconds or so in the grub it automatically boots ubuntu gnome).

I tried changing 'quiet_splash`in this picture with`nomodeset`.
[image: Screenshot]
**EDIT: This picture is not mine. I have an updated grub and ubuntu version 16.10.

but it just get's stuck, although I can now see some lines in the screen that tell me

`[OK] some text here`

`[OK] some more text`

`[OK] reached target local file systems
      starting run snappy firstboot setup...
      starting apparmor initialization...`

`[OK] Started hostname service. System Runlevel Changes.completed startup.p link was shut down....`

And then the boot gets stuck. I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with the GRUB or the installation itself since WIN10 was installed in legacy mode and Ubuntu Gnome was installed while booting in the pendrive bootable in legacy mode and not UEFI.

So both OS are installed in legacy (BIOS) mode.

The problem might be something related to the graphics card. Since I have an AMD APU and a MSI mobo (A68HM-P33 V2) that runs some kind of BIOS with fancy graphics (I think it's called UEFI) instead of the traditional BIOS and offers two boot options (UEFI and UEFI & Legacy).

TL;DR : Please if you have the minimum idea of what can be happening with this fresh install, at least point me in the right direction, just by telling me your toughts or sharing some info about where should I ask this question instead of this page.

Comment: I found some source that says that booting in recovery mode solves the issue. How can I do so ?

Comment: No no, sorry for the inconvenience of that screenshot but it's not mine, I just picked it from another Askubuntu to demonstrate what line I changed (removing the quiet splash) I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 in my dual boot.

Comment: Since it seems to be something related to graphic drivers, maybe I should try if debian works ?